# damaged screen brightness value in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, brightness

I have my iPhone screen brightness value using the below function in swift, the screen of this iPhone is in fine condition and the values are changing when brightness increase or decrease.

`let currentBrightness = UIScreen.main.brightness`.  //it gives the screen current brightness value

Values after printing :- **0.5160151720046997** then **0.5299854874610901** and so on

Actually, I am curios to know if this brightness values also changes in a **damaged screen**(brightness does not changes) **iPhone**.

Comment: Yes, it is the backlight value, not a measurement of light emitted.

Comment: so, you mean i won't get the values if my iPhone's screen is damaged??

Comment: I mean I would expect that you would still get differing brightness levels even though the screen brightness isn't changing (since it is broken).